# Bootable USB is not showing in Boot manager of ASUS B450M-A motherboard's UEFI

Tags: 22.04, live-usb, asus, rufus

I'm trying to put Ubuntu on a USB stick so I can install it on my desktop. I used Rufus to put the Ubuntu 22.04 iso on a USB stick, but when I open the boot menu/Boot manager I can't see the USB there, just my HDDs.

Devices:

- Motherboard: ASUS B450M-A
- USB: FAT32
- OS: Windows 10

Other info:

- Ubuntu ISO: 22.04-desktop-amd64
- Rufus: 3.21

Comment: If there is something like USB-HDD in your UEFI boot options then put that device first in the boot sequence. That's what the UEFI is calling your USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for the UEFI setup utility to list a bootable USB in the Boot tab -> boot sequence as a different type of USB device. Sometimes the UEFI gets it right and calls it something like "Ubuntu 22.04 USB" and sometimes it doesn't. It also depends on what application you used to make the Ubuntu live USB. ASUS laptops are often able to correctly identify an Ubuntu live USB which was made using Ubuntu's built-in Startup Disk Creator application.

If there is something like USB-HDD in your UEFI boot options then put that device first in the boot sequence. That's what the UEFI is calling your USB stick.

Comment: My old systems used HDD entry. My newer UEFI systems use UEFI:PMAP. Not sure if pmap is name or logo of flash drive as it is a OEM/store brand. Usually it is the brand or model of flash drive. All external drives boot from /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi which is a generic name. Windows uses same file name, but obviously a different file.